# SurfaceView Returns black Screen in droidreader

Tags: android, pdf, screenshot

I had tried alot & even search alot but i didn't found 
the solution about the **black screen** 
which i get by fetching the cache view on the **surface view**..
if is there any other way to capture the screen then let me know about this..
if i use another control & fetching the drawable cache of that control it also return null..
this is the code which i used to fetch the screen Image....

```
try {
    // Button btn = new Button(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
    b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(
                    "/mnt/sdcard/documents/" + new Date().getTime() + ".JPEG"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i had used this on the touch_up action of the surface view.....

**EDIT:**

```
public class DroidReaderActivity extends Activity {
private static final boolean LOG = false;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPTION_DIALOG = 2;

private static final int DIALOG_GET_PASSWORD = 1;
private static final int DIALOG_ABOUT = 2;
private static final int DIALOG_GOTO_PAGE = 3;
private static final int DIALOG_WELCOME = 4;
private static final int DIALOG_ENTER_ZOOM = 5;

private static final String PREFERENCE_EULA_ACCEPTED = "eula.accepted";
private static final String PREFERENCES_EULA = "eula";

protected DroidReaderView mReaderView = null;
protected DroidReaderDocument mDocument = null;

protected Menu m_ZoomMenu;

FrameLayout fl;

private String mFilename;
private String mTemporaryFilename;
private String mPassword;

private int mPageNo;

private SQLiteDatabase db;

static DatabaseConnectionAPI db_api;

private boolean mDocumentIsOpen = false;
private boolean mLoadedDocument = false;
private boolean mWelcomeShown = false;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            // Theoretically there could be a case where OnCreate() is called
            // again with the intent that was originally used to open the app,
            // which would revert to a previous document. Use setIntent
            // to update the intent that will be supplied back to OnCreate().
            setIntent(data);
            mTemporaryFilename = data.getDataString();
            if (mTemporaryFilename != null) {
                if (mTemporaryFilename.startsWith("file://")) {
                    mTemporaryFilename = mTemporaryFilename.substring(7);
                }
                mPassword = "";
                openDocumentWithDecodeAndLookup();
            }
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_CODE_OPTION_DIALOG:
        readPreferences();
        tryLoadLastFile();
        break;
    }
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("ONCREATE");

    db_api = new DatabaseConnectionAPI(this);
    try {
        db_api.createDataBase();
        db_api.openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // first, show the welcome if it hasn't been shown already:
    final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_EULA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!preferences.getBoolean(PREFERENCE_EULA_ACCEPTED, false)) {
        mWelcomeShown = true;
        preferences.edit().putBoolean(PREFERENCE_EULA_ACCEPTED, true).commit();
        showDialog(DIALOG_WELCOME);
    }

    if (mDocument == null)
        mDocument = new DroidReaderDocument();

    // Initialize the PdfRender engine
    PdfRender.setFontProvider(new DroidReaderFontProvider(this));

    // then build our layout. it's so simple that we don't use
    // XML for now.
    fl = new FrameLayout(this);

    mReaderView = new DroidReaderView(this, null, mDocument);

    // add the viewing area and the navigation
    fl.addView(mReaderView);
    setContentView(fl);

    readPreferences();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mFilename = savedInstanceState.getString("filename");
        if ((new File(mFilename)).exists()) {
            mPassword = savedInstanceState.getString("password");
            mDocument.mZoom = savedInstanceState.getFloat("zoom");
            mDocument.mRotation = savedInstanceState.getInt("rotation");
            mPageNo = savedInstanceState.getInt("page");
            mDocument.mMarginOffsetX = savedInstanceState.getInt("marginOffsetX");
            mDocument.mMarginOffsetY = savedInstanceState.getInt("marginOffsetY");
            mDocument.mContentFitMode = savedInstanceState.getInt("contentFitMode");
            openDocument();
            mLoadedDocument = true;
        }
        savedInstanceState.clear();
    }

        Timer mTimer = new Timer();

        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Bitmap saveBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(fl.getWidth(), fl.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    saveBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                            new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/documents/" + new Date().getTime() + ".JPEG"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if ((mDocument != null) && mDocument.isPageLoaded()) {
        outState.putFloat("zoom", mDocument.mZoom);
        outState.putInt("rotation", mDocument.mRotation);
        outState.putInt("page", mDocument.mPage.no);
        outState.putInt("offsetX", mDocument.mOffsetX);
        outState.putInt("offsetY", mDocument.mOffsetY);
        outState.putInt("marginOffsetX", mDocument.mMarginOffsetX);
        outState.putInt("marginOffsetY", mDocument.mMarginOffsetY);
        outState.putInt("contentFitMode", mDocument.mContentFitMode);
        outState.putString("password", mPassword);
        outState.putString("filename", mFilename);
        mDocument.closeDocument();
    }
}

public void onTap(float X, float Y) {
    float left, right, top, bottom;
    float width = mDocument.mDisplaySizeX;
    float height = mDocument.mDisplaySizeY;
    boolean prev = false;
    boolean next = false;

    if (mDocumentIsOpen) {
        left = width * (float) 0.25;
        right = width * (float) 0.75;
        top = height * (float) 0.25;
        bottom = height * (float) 0.75;

        if ((X < left) && (Y < top))
            prev = true;
        if ((X < left) && (Y > bottom))
            next = true;
        if ((X > right) && (Y < top))
            prev = true;
        if ((X > right) && (Y > bottom))
            next = true;
        if ((X > left) && (X < right) && (Y > bottom)) {
            Log.d("DroidReaderMetrics", String.format("Zoom = %5.2f%%", mDocument.mZoom * 100.0));
            Log.d("DroidReaderMetrics", String.format("Page size = (%2.0f,%2.0f)", mDocument.mPage.mMediabox[2]
                            - mDocument.mPage.mMediabox[0], mDocument.mPage.mMediabox[3] - mDocument.mPage.mMediabox[1]));
            Log.d("DroidReaderMetrics", String.format(
                    "Display size = (%d,%d)", mDocument.mDisplaySizeX, mDocument.mDisplaySizeY));
            Log.d("DroidReaderMetrics", String.format("DPI = (%d, %d)", mDocument.mDpiX, mDocument.mDpiY));
            Log.d("DroidReaderMetrics", String.format("Content size = (%2.0f,%2.0f)",
                    mDocument.mPage.mContentbox[2] - mDocument.mPage.mContentbox[0],
                    mDocument.mPage.mContentbox[3] - mDocument.mPage.mContentbox[1]));
            Log.d("DroidReaderMetrics", String.format("Content offset = (%2.0f,%2.0f)",
                    mDocument.mPage.mContentbox[0], mDocument.mPage.mContentbox[1]));
            Log.d("DroidReaderMetrics", String.format(
                    "Document offset = (%d,%d)", mDocument.mOffsetX, mDocument.mOffsetY));
        }
        if (next) {
            if (mDocument.havePage(1, true))
                openPage(1, true);
        } else if (prev) {
            if (mDocument.havePage(-1, true))
                openPage(-1, true);
        }
    }
}

protected void openDocument() {
    // Store the view details for the previous document and close it.
    if (mDocumentIsOpen) {
        mDocument.closeDocument();
        mDocumentIsOpen = false;
    }
    try {
        this.setTitle(mFilename);
        mDocument.open(mFilename, mPassword, mPageNo);
        openPage(0, true);
        mDocumentIsOpen = true;
    } catch (PasswordNeededException e) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_GET_PASSWORD);
    } catch (WrongPasswordException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_wrong_password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_opening_document, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

protected void openDocumentWithDecodeAndLookup() {
    try {
        mTemporaryFilename = URLDecoder.decode(mTemporaryFilename, "utf-8");

        // Do some sanity checks on the supplied filename.
        File f = new File(mTemporaryFilename);

        if ((f.exists()) && (f.isFile()) && (f.canRead())) {
            mFilename = mTemporaryFilename;
            openDocumentWithLookup();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_file_open_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_opening_document, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

protected void openDocumentWithLookup() {
    readOrWriteDB(false);
    openDocument();
}

protected void openPage(int no, boolean isRelative) {
    try {
        if (!(no == 0 && isRelative))
            mDocument.openPage(no, isRelative);
        this.setTitle(new File(mFilename).getName()
                + String.format(" (%d/%d)", mDocument.mPage.no, mDocument.mDocument.pagecount));
        mPageNo = mDocument.mPage.no;
    } catch (PageLoadException e) {
    }
}



private void readPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    if (prefs.getString("zoom_type", "0").equals("0")) {
        float zoom = Float.parseFloat(prefs.getString("zoom_percent", "50"));
        if ((1 <= zoom) && (1000 >= zoom)) {
            mDocument.setZoom(zoom / 100, false);
        }
    } else {
        mDocument.setZoom(Float.parseFloat(prefs.getString("zoom_type", "0")), false);
    }

    if (prefs.getBoolean("dpi_auto", true)) {
        // read the display's DPI
        mDocument.setDpi((int) metrics.xdpi, (int) metrics.ydpi);
    } else {
        int dpi = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("dpi_manual", "160"));
        if ((dpi < 1) || (dpi > 4096))
            dpi = 160; // sanity check fallback
        mDocument.setDpi(dpi, dpi);
    }

    if (prefs.getBoolean("tilesize_by_factor", true)) {
        // set the tile size for rendering by factor
        Float factor = Float.parseFloat(prefs.getString("tilesize_factor", "1.5"));
        mDocument.setTileMax((int) (metrics.widthPixels * factor), (int) (metrics.heightPixels * factor));
    } else {
        int tilesize_x = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("tilesize_x", "640"));
        int tilesize_y = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("tilesize_x", "480"));
        if (metrics.widthPixels < metrics.heightPixels) {
            mDocument.setTileMax(tilesize_x, tilesize_y);
        } else {
            mDocument.setTileMax(tilesize_y, tilesize_x);
        }
    }

    boolean invert = prefs.getBoolean("invert_display", false);
    mDocument.setDisplayInvert(invert);
    mReaderView.setDisplayInvert(invert);

    if (prefs.getBoolean("full_screen", false)) {
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
        this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    mDocument.mHorizontalScrollLock = prefs.getBoolean("horizontal_scroll_lock", false);
}

protected void setZoom(float newZoom) {
    newZoom = newZoom / (float) 100.0;
    if (newZoom > 16.0)
        newZoom = (float) 16.0;
    if (newZoom < 0.0625)
        newZoom = (float) 0.0625;
    mDocument.setZoom(newZoom, false);
}

protected void tryLoadLastFile() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mFilename = prefs.getString("last_open_file", "");
    if (mFilename != null) {
        if ((mFilename.length() > 0) && ((new File(mFilename)).exists())) {
            // Don't URL-decode the filename, as that's presumably already been done.
            mPassword = "";
            openDocumentWithLookup();
            mLoadedDocument = true;
        }
    }
}

}
```

**DroidReaderView:**

```
public class DroidReaderView extends SurfaceView implements OnGestureListener,
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, DroidReaderDocument.RenderListener {

public static Path mPath = new Path();
private static StringBuffer sbx = new StringBuffer();
private static StringBuffer sby = new StringBuffer();
public static Paint mPaint = new Paint();
public static Paint nullpaint = new Paint();
private String sx, sy, sbx_str, sby_str;
public static Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas();
private int pid = 1;

/**
 * Debug helper
 */
protected final static String TAG = "DroidReaderView";
protected final static boolean LOG = false;

/**
 * our view thread which does the drawing
 */
public DroidReaderViewThread mThread;

/**
 * our gesture detector
 */
protected final GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

/**
 * our context
 */
protected final DroidReaderActivity mActivity;

/**
 * our SurfaceHolder
 */
protected final SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

public static DroidReaderDocument mDocument;

protected boolean mDisplayInvert;

/**
 * constructs a new View
 * 
 * @param context
 *            Context for the View
 * @param attrs
 *            attributes (may be null)
 */
public DroidReaderView(final DroidReaderActivity activity, AttributeSet attrs, DroidReaderDocument document) {
    super(activity, attrs);

    mActivity = activity;
    mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
    mDocument = document;
    mDocument.mRenderListener = this;

    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

    // tell the SurfaceHolder to inform this thread on
    // changes to the surface
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
}

/* event listeners: */

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    mThread.c = canvas;
    mThread.c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

    mThread.c.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mThread.c);

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onFling(): notifying ViewThread");
    mThread.mScroller.fling(0, 0, -(int) velocityX, -(int) velocityY, -4096, 4096, -4096, 4096);
    mThread.triggerRepaint();
    return true;
}

/* keyboard events: */

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown(), keycode " + keyCode);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onKeyUp(), keycode " + keyCode);
    return false;
}

/* interface for the GestureListener: */

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onLongPress(): ignoring!");
}

@Override
public void onNewRenderedPixmap() {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "new rendered pixmap was signalled");
    mThread.triggerRepaint();
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onScroll(), distance vector: " + distanceX + "," + distanceY);
    mDocument.offset((int) distanceX, (int) distanceY, true);
    mThread.triggerRepaint();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onShowPress(): ignoring!");
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // Pass the tap, and the window dimensions, to the activity to process.
    mActivity.onTap(e.getX(), e.getY());
    return true;
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    sx = Float.toString(mX);
    sbx.append(sx);
    sbx.append(",");

    mY = y;
    sy = Float.toString(mY);
    sby.append(sy);
    sby.append(",");

    sbx_str = sbx.toString();
    sby_str = sby.toString();
}

private void draw_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        sx = Float.toString(mX);
        sbx.append(sx);
        sbx.append(",");
        mY = y;
        sy = Float.toString(mY);
        sby.append(sy);
        sby.append(",");
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    sx = Float.toString(mX);
    sbx.append(sx);
    sbx.append(",");

    sy = Float.toString(mY);
    sby.append(sy);
    sby.append(",");

    mPath.reset();

    sbx_str = sbx.toString().trim();
    sby_str = sby.toString().trim();

    insert(TAGS.presentation_id, mDocument.mPage.no, sbx_str, sby_str);
    sbx = new StringBuffer();
    sby = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println(sbx_str.trim());
    System.out.println(sby_str.trim());

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        draw_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        try {

            // Button btn = new Button(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
            // buildDrawingCache();
            // setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            // Bitmap b = getDrawingCache();
            // b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(
            // "/mnt/sdcard/documents/" + new Date().getTime() + ".JPEG"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    invalidate();

    if (LOG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent(): notifying mGestureDetector");
        invalidate();
    }
    if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent(): notifying ViewThread");
    mDocument
            .offset((int) event.getX() * 20, (int) event.getY() * 20, true);
    mThread.triggerRepaint();
    return true;
}

/* surface events: */

public void setDisplayInvert(boolean invert) {
    if (mThread != null)
        mThread.setPainters(invert);
    mDisplayInvert = invert;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged(): size " + width + "x" + height);
    mDocument.startRendering(width, height);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated(): starting ViewThread");
    mThread = new DroidReaderViewThread(holder, mActivity, mDocument);
    mThread.setPainters(mDisplayInvert);
    mThread.start();
}

/* render events */

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed(): dying");
    mDocument.stopRendering();
    boolean retry = true;
    mThread.mRun = false;
    mThread.interrupt();
    while (retry) {
        try {
            mThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
```

**DroidReaderViewThread :**

Thread that cares for blitting Pixmaps onto the Canvas and handles scrolling

```
class DroidReaderViewThread extends Thread {

public Canvas c = new Canvas();
private Cursor mCursor;
private Path mPath1 = new Path();
private StringBuffer sbx_read, sby_read;
public static Paint mPaint2 = new Paint();
public static Paint mPaint3 = new Paint();
Path old_path = new Path();

/**
 * Debug helper
 */
protected final static String TAG = "DroidReaderViewThread";
protected final static boolean LOG = false;
/**
 * the SurfaceHolder for our Surface
 */
protected final SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

/**
 * Paint for not (yet) rendered parts of the page
 */
protected final Paint mEmptyPaint;
/**
 * Paint for filling the display when there is no PdfPage (yet)
 */
protected final Paint mNoPagePaint;
/**
 * Paint for the status text
 */
protected final Paint mStatusPaint;

/**
 * Flag that our thread should be running
 */
protected boolean mRun = true;

/**
 * our scroller
 */
protected final Scroller mScroller;

protected final DroidReaderDocument mDocument;

/**
 * Background render thread, using the SurfaceView programming scheme
 * 
 * @param holder
 *            our SurfaceHolder
 * @param context
 *            the Context for our drawing
 */
public DroidReaderViewThread(SurfaceHolder holder, Context context, DroidReaderDocument document) {
    // store a reference to our SurfaceHolder
    mSurfaceHolder = holder;

    mDocument = document;

    // initialize Paints for non-Pixmap areas
    mEmptyPaint = new Paint();
    mNoPagePaint = new Paint();
    mStatusPaint = new Paint();

    setPainters(false);

    // the scroller, i.e. the object that calculates/interpolates
    // positions for scrolling/jumping/flinging
    mScroller = new Scroller(context);
}

/**
 * ll this does the actual drawing to the Canvas for our surface
 */

private void doDraw() {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "drawing...");
    c = null;
    try {
        c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        if (!mDocument.isPageLoaded()) {
            // no page/document loaded
            if (LOG)
                Log.d(TAG, "no page loaded.");
            c.drawRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), mNoPagePaint);
        } else if (mDocument.havePixmap()) {
            // we have both page and Pixmap, so draw:
            // background:
            if (LOG)
                Log.d(TAG, "page loaded, rendering pixmap");
            c.drawRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), mEmptyPaint);
            Log.d("CALL", "CALL");
            c.drawBitmap(mDocument.mView.mBuf, 0,
                    mDocument.mView.mViewBox.width(), -mDocument.mOffsetX + mDocument.mView.mViewBox.left,
                    -mDocument.mOffsetY + mDocument.mView.mViewBox.top,
                    mDocument.mView.mViewBox.width(), mDocument.mView.mViewBox.height(), false, null);

            try {
                Log.d("Reading", "Reading");
                mCursor = DroidReaderActivity.db_api
                        .ExecuteQueryGetCursor("SELECT * FROM path WHERE page_no=" + mDocument.mPage.no
                                + " AND presentation_id=" + TAGS.presentation_id + ";");

                if (!mCursor.equals(null)) {

                    mCursor.moveToFirst();
                    float x1 = 0, y1 = 0;
                    int pid = 0;
                    do {

                        sbx_read = new StringBuffer();
                        sbx_read.append(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("x_path")));
                        sby_read = new StringBuffer();
                        sby_read.append(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("y_path")));

                        String[] sbx_read_array = sbx_read.toString().trim().split(",");
                        String[] sby_read_array = sby_read.toString().trim().split(",");

                        for (int i = 0; i < sbx_read_array.length; i++) {

                            x1 = Float.parseFloat(sbx_read_array[i].toString());
                            y1 = Float.parseFloat(sby_read_array[i].toString());

                            if (pid != mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("path_id"))) {

                                pid = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("path_id"));

                                Log.d("New Path Id.",
                                        String.valueOf(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("path_id"))));

                                mPath1.reset();
                                mPath1.moveTo(x1, y1);
                            } else {
                                Log.d("Path id repeating.",
                                        String.valueOf(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("path_id"))));
                            }

                            mPath1.lineTo(x1, y1);
                            c.drawPath(mPath1, DroidReaderView.mPaint);
                        }
                    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
                    mCursor.close();
                    Log.d("Read mode Complete", "Read mode Complete");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.d("read Cursor", e.getMessage().toString());
            }

        } else {
            // page loaded, but no Pixmap yet
            if (LOG)
                Log.d(TAG, "page loaded, but no active Pixmap.");
            c.drawRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), mEmptyPaint);
            mPaint3.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint3.setDither(true);
            mPaint3.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mPaint3.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint3.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint3.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint3.setStrokeWidth(12);
            mPaint3.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            c.drawPath(old_path, mPaint3);
        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {

            mPaint2.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint2.setDither(true);
            mPaint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            mPaint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint2.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint2.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint2.setStrokeWidth(12);
            c.drawPath(DroidReaderView.mPath, mPaint2);
            // DroidReaderView.mPath.reset();
            // old_path = DroidReaderView.mPath;

        }
        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}

/**
 * Main Thread loop
 */
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void run() {
    while (mRun) {
        boolean doSleep = true;
        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
                if (LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "new scroll offset");
                doSleep = false;
                int oldX = mDocument.mOffsetX;
                int oldY = mDocument.mOffsetY;
                mDocument.offset(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY(), true);
                if ((oldX == mDocument.mOffsetX) && (oldY == mDocument.mOffsetY))
                    mScroller.abortAnimation();
            } else {
                mScroller.abortAnimation();
            }
        }
        doDraw();
        // if we're allowed, we will go to sleep now
        if (doSleep) {
            try {
                // nothing to do, wait for someone waking us up:
                if (LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "ViewThread going to sleep");

                // between
                // the check for pending interrupts and the sleep() which
                // could lead to a not-handled repaint request:
                if (!this.interrupted())
                    Thread.sleep(3600000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                if (LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "ViewThread woken up");
            }
        }
    }
    // mRun is now false, so we shut down.
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "shutting down");
}

public void setPainters(boolean invert) {
    // initialize Paints for non-Pixmap areas
    mEmptyPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mNoPagePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mStatusPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    if (invert)
        mEmptyPaint.setColor(0xff000000); // black
    else
        mEmptyPaint.setColor(0xffc0c0c0); // light gray

    if (invert)
        mNoPagePaint.setColor(0xff000000); // black
    else
        mNoPagePaint.setColor(0xff303030); // dark gray

    if (invert)
        mStatusPaint.setColor(0xff000000); // black
    else
        mStatusPaint.setColor(0xff808080); // medium gray
}

public void triggerRepaint() {
    if (LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "repaint triggered");
    interrupt();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this, and its works fine in my case,

Here imageFrame is `FrameLayout`, root view of my View which I want to save as bitmap..

```
Bitmap saveBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageFrame.getWidth(), imageFrame.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(saveBitmap);
imageFrame.draw(c);
```

Try replacing imageFrame with your view.

**EDIT:**

```
    Date date = new Date();
    File filename = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile(), "" + date.getTime() + ".jpg");
    try
    {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        saveBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fOut);
        try
        {
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
private void doDraw() {

  int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX; 
  BitmapConfig conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types 
  Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap 
  c = new Canvas(bmp);
```

Comment: then how should i get it to my external storage..
you are doing to set the image to canvas but i wan to fetch the image from canvas or frame layout or surfaceview....

Comment: i agree with your code but my problem i am not getting the screen image..
as i am not getting the screen Image then how can i set it to the canvas or frame layout....

Comment: You are misunderstood the code, can you put your whole code, so i can check it. what is view in your code?

Comment: still black Image......
not working....
when i put button instead of surfaceview its giving perfect image of button but its not working in surfaceview...
check the updated code.

Comment: i had just removed it..
it is in comment of DroidReaderActivity code..
its nothing where i am adding the mReaderView to framelayout
(fl.addView(mReaderView))

comment it & place this line...

Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("clickMe");

you'll get button on screen n Image o that button also in sdcard

Comment: Try with this code, View rootView = <Your_Activity_Name>.this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
  rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  rootView.buildDrawingCache();
  Bitmap bitmap = rootView.getDrawingCache();

Comment: its just returning Title bar not the surface view...
in the Image it just show title else black screen...
but i had give the gray color to the canvas in DroidReaderViewThread...

Comment: Is your drawing bitmap and DroidReaderView in different threads?

Comment: I am using a PDFRender class which returns Integer array contains PDF page data which i placed in Canvas through DrawBitmap method in DroidReaderViewThread..... which assign to the DroidReaderView,.......

Comment: Which one is your actual canvas which render pdf file view(means draw pdf file on screen)?

Comment: int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;

BitmapConfig conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp); now when you completed drawing then use bmp to save as bitmap to file (use bmp.compress()). Try this.

Comment: Look at my newly edit and use Bitmap bmp as a global variable and after completed drawing it to canvas write it to file.

Comment: not working....
but in this case it will return only the PDF bitmap 
this image will not show the annotation on the PDF....
thats y i need to capture the screen only....

Comment: do not we have any kind of logic to capture the whole screen as Image in android
.?????

Comment: The first logic which I mentioned in my answer, was working but here both are running on different thread thats why you can not get it. Actually If you got current window's rootview you can easily convert it to bitmap.

Comment: yes i agree with that but in that case i am just getting a title bar only else black screen....

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android question's  second answer. He was able to take screenshot of his pdf page.

Comment: i read that & i had already done that option but in my case it gives me memory overflow error..
as PDF may have number of pages & number of images in pages with different density....
so i took this way to render each page every time when it call....
it mean a page call whole PDF(page) regenerate....