# How can I take a screenshot of a video, in android

Tags: android, video, screen, paint, capture

I have a video playing, and at some point, i need to pause the video, take a capture, and use then that image, to modify it, in a paint activity. The problem is that if, i try to save the video, the picture will be black (tried with `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` )........
Is it possible to take a screenshot of a video?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714964/capture-screenshot-of-playing-video-and-mailing-that-screen-shot

Comment: Like i said, the getDrawingCache, setDrawingCache, does not work, because, the videoView extends an SurfaceView, wich has its content not go through the drawing cache, thus getting the black screen instead of a capture of the video

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried  `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(String, int)?`

Comment: I am now trying with extractThumbnail, because i should not use the file path, and also, need to take the screen in the exact moment i am.

Comment: now, extractThumbnail, returns null, and of createVideoThumbnail, i don't understand it, even if i give the filename, and the kind of the bitmap, how can i choose from exactly what second of the video i want to take the screencapture?

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337505/android-capture-video-frame ?

Comment: the last link, with that getVideoFrame function worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Another thing, for this function, at getFrameAtTime() you can pass the time for what frame to get. My question is, how can i get the time from a videoView (seconds), i tried videoView.getCurrentPosition, but it's not really precise

Comment: @BudaGavril thanks, i was able to do this with a video stored locally on the phone. However, when the video is streamed in the VideoView, I can't seem to capture the video frame. Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Link ..

Hope it may help you

[Screen capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android)

```
Bitmap saveBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageFrame.getWidth(), 
 imageFrame.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(saveBitmap);
imageFrame.draw(c);
```

For more info try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505093/how-to-capture-screenshot-of-surfaceview-with-background)

& [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275225/surfaceview-returns-black-screen-in-droidreader)

Comment: I;ve been looking at thes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505093/how-to-capture-screenshot-of-surfaceview-with-background
But i don't get it, overlaying 2 bitmaps, ok, how can this help me? I got an bitmap thats set on the canvas, and you draw on it, (its transparent, so u can see the video) and i have got an VideoView (extends Surface View), that is in the back of the transparent canvas. Now when i take a picture, i have to include the canvas and also the videoview.

Comment: @rosualin so you want to include videoview only or canvas too

Comment: both. I need to include the video view and the canvas

Answer (score -2):

I Think u should use screencaputre application in android that is use full to you...
rather than the best way for u can connect your android with PC than start the video and pause it, than in keyboard press print screen, and in paint software press ctrl+V (paste) and save in jpeg format than you get the screen shot/image...

Comment: I need to make an application that does this, I have to make it so it would be independent of pc's or other applications

Comment: Can You Use This link ? http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/08/android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast/  I Hope this is help ful

Comment: nope, sorry, but it has to be programatically, no pc, no other applications, no usb connection, just from the app, you click a button and then it does the screenshot