# How to get a photo of video playing inside FrameLayout in android?

Tags: android, photo, android-framelayout

I m playing a video inside a framelayout and when i press button, i want to take a photo of that video frame and i want to save it to sdcard. How can i do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557623/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-video-in-android

Answer (score 2):

If by photo you mean a thumbnail then the following code could be of use to you:

```
int id = **"The Video's ID"**
ImageView iv = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id,
MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

You then just have to link this code to a button press using the Android `onClickListner`.
A simple example using a listener would be like this:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```

Finally to save the thumbnail to the SD card you should take a look at this answer:

[Android Save images to SQLite or SDCard or memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273008/android-save-images-to-sqlite-or-sdcard-or-memory)

Comment: i dont play a video actually, i m playing another android device's cam so there is not a path or id to video